# how to explicitly commit inside a transactional class in spring boot application?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I am using transactional annotation on a class in my spring boot application .In one of this class method, we are downloading content from remote location and updating database .This download is running in loop.
I want to explicitly commit after 50 downloads in this method only.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can achieve this..

1. Either maintain counter local variable state in a class and do the required stuff when it reach out to 50.
2. Try to open two transaction in that method and update counter in db via first transaction, and second transaction will take care for  rest of the things.

> ```
> Transaction transaction;
>
> transaction = session.beginTransaction();
>
> ... (operations in the context of transaction)
>
> transaction.commit();
>
> ... (other commands outside of any transaction) transaction = session.beginTransaction();
>
> ... (and so on and so forth ....
> ```